# Writing \\ to a File

Tags: macros, write

I have a local class that a number of people use.  One of the new things I want it to do is write out various user-defined data to a file, so that a follow-up LaTeX document can do something different, but with the same user-defined parameters.  I'm somewhat new to reading and writing external files, so my question may be elementary.

Here's an MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%% USER CONTROLS THIS DEFINITION
\def\userdef{abc}        % Works Great
%\def\userdef{abc\\def}  % Breaks \write
%% I CONTROL THE FOLLOWING
\def\userdefContent{\noexpand\def\noexpand\userdef{\userdef}}%
\newwrite\tempfile%
\immediate\openout\tempfile=userdata.tex
\immediate\write\tempfile{\userdefContent}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\end{document}
```

The user defines some known variable using a `\def` and I'd like to write it to a file in the form of `\def\userdef{blah blah blah}` where `blah blah blah` is how the user defined it.  In this way, I can `\input` it into another file and have that second document pre-initialized with the same data the user defined for the first round.

The problem is that there are some user variables I want to write that may be populated with `\\` characters which, apparently, break the `\write`.  Uncomment the one line in the MWE to demonstrate this.

I am flexible on a solution.  Ideally, I would like my output file to contain

```
\def \userdef {abc\\def}
```

but I would be willing to settle for

```
\def \userdef {abc*LINEFEED*def}
```

where `*LINEFEED*` is an arbitrary string sequence to alert me that I will later need to stick back in a `\\`.  I would even, as a last resort, settle for

```
\def \userdef {abc def}
```

where the `\\` has been stripped.

I suppose I would, if there were no other solution, instruct the userbase not to use `\\` in their `\def` but some other macro that I define (which I can then redefine prior to the `\write`).  But I think they might resist this last approach.  I also would resist it, because it would break backward compatibility to older documents.

I am also open to a totally different approach, if there is a standard LaTeX way of transferring data between different documents.  I would add that I have a `stringstings` solution that works when `\userdef` is composed purely of catcode 11 and 12 material and `\\` characters, but I can't guarantee in advance that the user won't stick some other macros in his `\def`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to disable the expandability of `\\` when doing the write. But in general `\write` is problematic when "free" input is allowed: `\textbf` or similar commands will surely break.

It's better to build an "immediate" version of `\protected@write`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% get a copy of `\protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\makeatother

\newwrite\tempfile

\begin{document}
\def\userdef{abc\\def}  % Breaks \write

\immediate\openout\tempfile=userdata.tex
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\tempfile{\let\\\relax}{\userdef}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Note that `\protected@iwrite` has, like its sibling, a second argument where declarations can be performed to change the meaning of commands for the scope of the write; in this case I set `\\` equal to `\relax` so it becomes unexpandable. Without this the output would be

```
abc\protect \\def
```

With the temporary assignment it is

```
abc\\def
```

as desired.

A possible simplification is using the same method LaTeX uses for `\typeout` (thanks to David Carlisle for suggesting it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\protected@iwrite#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup\set@display@protect
  #2% local assignments
  \immediate\write#1{#3}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\userdef{abc\\\textbf{def}}

\immediate\openout\tempfile=userdata.tex
\makeatletter
\protected@iwrite\tempfile{}{\def\protect\userdef{\userdef}}
\immediate\closeout\tempfile
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The output is `\def\userdef{abc\\\textbf {def}}`. Notice that also `\textbf` is OK. Fragile commands need `\protect`, of course.

Comment: I am still not able to overcome one impediment with this approach.  When I give the argument to the iwrite as `{\noexpand\def\noexpand\userdef{\userdef}}` hoping to get `\def\userdef{abc\\def}` in the file, I instead get `\def abc\\def{abc\\def}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `{\def\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\userdef{\userdef}}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\noexpand` isn't a LaTeX command, use `\protect` (also `\def` isn't expandable anyway) so `\protected@iwrite\tempfile{\let\\\relax}{\def\protect\userdef{\userdef}}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes oops our comments crossed I told you not to use `\noexpand` and egreg said to use three of them. (we said same thing really though).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "Ditto."  Indeed, I thought a Clash of the Titans was about to unfold.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes oh there is one minor difference between the suggestions: egreg's works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I found that when using the `\protect` approach inside a class file (rather than inside a document), it left the `\protect` in the output, which was not desired.