# Replacing some macro tokens in a list before \write ing

Tags: macros, expansion, write

I'm trying to hack a bibliography package (`amsrefs`), and fall into the following problem. I'm trying to convert the amsrefs format back to .bib files. This doesn't quite work, because strings get modified; i.e. a name such as `Goode, Johnny~B.` gets transformed to `Goode, Johnny\nobreakspace {}B.` and this is what appears in the output stream when I try to \immediate\write it.

How do I force the `\nobreakspace` and/or the more complicated `\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M` macros to evaluate to `~`?

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve, and the problem: saving this file into 'test.tex' and compiling it produces 'test.bib', which contains the lines

```
%Output bibliography test.tex to test.bib
@Book{
 title={Goode, Johhny\protect \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}B.}
}
```

and not just "title={Goode, Johnny~B.}"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\makeatletter

\def\printtitle#1{\immediate\write\bibfile{ title={#1}}}

\BibSpec{book}{%
  +{}{\immediate\write\bibfile{@Book\@charlb}}{transition}
  +{}{\printtitle}{title}
  +{}{\immediate\write\bibfile{\@charrb}}{transition}
}

\begin{document}
\immediate\newwrite\bibfile
\immediate\openout\bibfile=\jobname.bib
\immediate\write\bibfile{\@percentchar Output bibliography \jobname.tex to \jobname.bib}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{test}{book}{
  title={Goode, Johhny~B.}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\immediate\closeout\bibfile
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you show some minimal, but compilable code?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37792/write-environment-body-verbatim-to-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `\immediate` version of `\write` (see [Writing \\ to a File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/writing-to-a-file)). The `\protected@iwrite` command has one argument more, where to give settings that are applied when writing. For writing a literal `~` you need to make it (temporarily) equivalent to `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% get a copy of `\protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}

\newcommand{\bib@write}[1]{%
  \protected@iwrite\bibfile
   {\let~\relax}%
   {#1}%
}

\def\printtitle#1{\bib@write{ title={#1}}}

\BibSpec{book}{%
  +{}{\bib@write{@Book\@charlb}}{transition}
  +{}{\printtitle}{title}
  +{}{\bib@write{\@charrb}}{transition}
}
\newwrite\bibfile
\immediate\openout\bibfile=\jobname.bib
\bib@write{\@percentchar Output bibliography \jobname.tex to \jobname.bib}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{test}{book}{
  title={Goode, Johhny~B.}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\immediate\closeout\bibfile
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of `\jobname.bib`:

```
%Output bibliography bartholdi.tex to bartholdi.bib
@Book{
 title={Goode, Johhny~B.}
}
```