# Incomplete \iffalse error using answers package

Tags: answers

This code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}

\Opensolutionfile{foo}

\begin{document}

%\Writetofile{foo}{whatever} % OK
\Writetofile{foo}{\noexpand\chapter{bar}} % fails

\end{document}
```

produces this error

```
Output from handle foo going to foo.tex
(c:\eb\tex\q.aux)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 10.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.10 \Writetofile{foo}{\noexpand\chapter{bar}}
                                               % fails
```

The construction worked perfectly on another computer (now broken) with a relatively new MiKTeX installation. On this windows 7 machine I'm running

```
C:\eb\tex>pdflatex -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

I have looked at the related questions with a similar `\iffalse` error message, to no avail.

Comment: Use `\protect`: that's the LaTeX mechanism

Comment: Where do I put the `\protect`? Instead of `\noexpand`? Any idea why this used to work? Please post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @EthanBolker See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194718/latex-answers-package-and-cyrilic-symbols-in-enumerate-environment for understanding why the package was updated in a way that doesn't allow `\noexpand` any more.

Comment: This interchange and the quick answer is a tribute to the wizards here. It took me _much_ longer to isolate the MNWE from my big document than for you all to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `answers` package (now) uses the standard LaTeX2e `\protect` mechanism in writing to external files. The implementation detail here is unimportant, but the key outcome is that you should not use the TeX primitive `\noexpand` but rather the `\protect` command

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}

\Opensolutionfile{foo}

\begin{document}

%\Writetofile{foo}{whatever} % OK
\Writetofile{foo}{\protect\chapter{bar}} % fails

\end{document}
```

(Back-story: LaTeX2e's mechanism alters the definition of `\protect` depending on the context. Here, `\noexpand` is not the right choice.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other solution

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{answers}

\Opensolutionfile{foo}

\begin{document}

\begin{Filesave}{foo}
\chapter{bar}
\end{Filesave}



\makeatletter
\immediate\write\foo@file{\unexpanded{\section{too}}}
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

you can define new command with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mtwrite}[2]{%
\immediate\write\csname #1@file\endcsname{\unexpanded{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

and use it

```
\mtwrite{foo}{\chapter{too}}
```

Comment: Avoiding `\write` is the exact reason why `answers.sty` was modified. And `\unexpanded` is not correct, because there usually *are* things you want to be expanded in what you write out.

Comment: @egreg can you explain your comment? (for bad english user) what is the problem of \unexpanded?

Comment: Nothing in the argument to `\unexpanded` is expanded; if you want to have, say, `\theanswer` or any other current value, you won't get it.