# answers package + environ package + equation won't compile

Tags: answers

This MWE works perfectly when the I comment out `equation` in the teacher environment. With that equation in place I get this error:

```
(C:\Users\Ethan.Bolker\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\trimspaces\trimspac
es.sty)) 
Output from handle answersout going to answersout.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.30 \end{teacher}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\answersout}{answersout}

\NewEnviron{teacher}{%
\Writetofile{\answersout}{\BODY }
}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{\answersout}

An equation in the master file:
%
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{teacher}
In answersout: expand a macro: \LaTeX.
Try an equation:
% comment out the next three lines and the document compiles
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4
\end{equation}
\end{teacher}

\Closesolutionfile{\answersout}
\input{\answersout}
\end{document}
```

Some history. A previous problem with the `answers` package led me to this question:
[Incomplete \iffalse error using answers package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235625/incomplete-iffalse-error-using-answers-package)

In fact that was the first error I saw when I encountered this problem. That error message was replaced by the one above when I made my example minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the `\protected@iwrite` mechanism with a stronger one that has the defect that it expands *nothing*. So if you want to add titles to the teacher's notes you have to work in two steps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\answersout}{answersout}

\newcounter{teacher}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{teacher}{%
  \stepcounter{teacher}%
  (See teacher note \theteacher)
  \Writetofile\answersout{%
    \protect\subsection*{Teacher's note \theteacher}%
  }
  \begingroup
  \def\protected@iwrite##1##2##3{\immediate\write##1{##3}}%
  \Writetofile\answersout{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{\answersout}

An equation in the master file:
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{teacher}
In answersout: expand a macro: \LaTeX.
Try an equation:
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4
\end{equation}
\end{teacher}

\Closesolutionfile{\answersout}

\section*{Teacher's notes}
\input{\answersout}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `\BODY` gets expanded before being written to the file. The result isn't plain text, and disaster follows. Protecting doesn't help, because the meaning of `\BODY` is lost at `\end{teacher}`. One way around this is to store the bodies of the environments using globally defined macros called `\tchI`, `\tchII`, `\tchIII`, etc. These can be protected, and written to the file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\answersout}{answersout}

\newcounter{tchcount} 
\setcounter{tchcount}{0}

\NewEnviron{teacher}{%
\stepcounter{tchcount}
\global\expandafter\let\csname tch\Roman{tchcount}\endcsname\BODY
\Writetofile{\answersout}{\expandafter\protect\csname tch\Roman{tchcount}\endcsname}
}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{\answersout}

\begin{teacher}
Try an equation:
\begin{equation}
2+2 = 4
\end{equation}
\end{teacher}

\begin{teacher}
And another
\begin{equation}
1+1 = 2
\end{equation}
\end{teacher}

\Closesolutionfile{\answersout}
\input{\answersout}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both your answer and @egreg s work. I've upvoted both. I accepted his because it seems just a little less magical to me.