# Is it possible to get the package listofsymbols to recognize the \cdots command?

Tags: amsmath, nomenclature

I am trying use the package `listofsymbols` to define a symbol to be included in a list of symbols in a book. I have problems using the command `\newsym` to define a symbol which involves the command `\cdots`.

The following is a simple symbol definition that illustrates the problem:

```
\opensymdef
\newsym[A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}}
\closesymdef
```

When a document which includes the symbols file is compiled, `pdflatex` issues the the following error messages:

```
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
```

The description of the error is:

```
... family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

If `\cdots` is replaced with a string such as `xxxx` or a command such as `\alpha`, in the above symbol definition, then `pdflatex` compiles the document.

Could someone help me sort out this problem. Any help would be appreciated highly.

Comment: Please add to your question a *complete* yet minimal document illustrating the problem mentioned.

Comment: I ask you for this MWE since this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{listofsymbols}

\opensymdef
\newsym[A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}}
\closesymdef


\begin{document}    
test

The symbol \sFam means \sFamdoc
\end{document}` works flawlessly in my system (TeX Live2014).

Comment: Thanks four your answer Gonzalo. I have tried out your example exactly as you have written it. However, it still does not work for me. I also use TeXLive 2014.

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to the preamble of the exact code I gave in my previous comment and compile the document, open the `.log` file and search for the `*File List*` section and add this list as an edit to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Gonzalo Medina. Analysis of the difference between your code and mine led me to discover the source of my problem. When I use your code in the context of my original document it fails to compile; but if I use your code in isolation it compiles without problems at all. I discovered that one of the packages I used in my context, the **amsmath** package, was the cause of the problem. My code works if the **\usepackage{amsmath}** command is commented out. Unfortunately, I need the **amsmath** package in order to access the **\numberwithin** command.

Comment: You're right. There can be problems with `amsmath`; I've provided a possible solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The error is in the `listofsymbols` package that uses `\immediate\write`, which is wrong and is the cause of your troubles.

Loading `amsmath` after the list of new symbols is not really a solution, because other commands can be affected; for instance, `\sqrt` will not work whatever order you use.

Better is changing `\immediate\write` into `\protected@iwrite` as defined in [one of my answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192133/4427).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listofsymbols} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% get a copy of \protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
% patch \addsymline to use \protected@iwrite instead of \immediate\write
\xpatchcmd{\addsymline}
  {\immediate\write#5}
  {\protected@iwrite{#5}{}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\opensymdef 
\newsym[A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}} 
\closesymdef

\begin{document} 

\listofsymbols

test The symbol \sFam means \sFamdoc 
\end{document}
```

[image]

With this redefinitions some symbols can still give problems; in this case add `\protect` before the offending one.

By the way, you shouldn't use `\cdots` in this context, but simply `\dots`: an ellipsis between commas should always be with low dots.

Comment: Thanks a lot egreg. I have tried out your code. It works even for **\sqrt**. I also appreciate your comments on **\cdots** and **\dots**. I have just read the **amsmath** user guide on dots and discovered the contextually flexible dots such as **\dotsc**, **\dotsb**, etc. Great stuff.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

as egreg mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228801/is-it-possible-to-get-the-package-listofsymbols-to-recognize-the-cdots-command/229009?noredirect=1#comment540504_229009) this is just a partial solution.

In the comments to the question, the problem has been reduced to the use of the `amsmath` package together with `listofsymbols`; this simple document

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[draft]{listofsymbols} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\opensymdef 
\newsym[A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}} 
\closesymdef 

\begin{document} 
test The symbol \sFam means \sFamdoc 
\end{document}
```

triggers the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\DN@ ->\def \next@ 
                   
l.6 ...A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}}
                                                  
?
```

The problem can be solved by loading `amsmath` *after* all the definitions of symbols, as in:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[draft]{listofsymbols} 

\opensymdef 
\newsym[A family of sets]{sFam}{A_{1},\cdots,A_{n}} 
\closesymdef 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
test The symbol \sFam means \sFamdoc 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `\sqrt` in the final argument to `\newsym` and enjoy. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg you're right. I'll add a remark to my answer linking to your comment and leave this as a provisional answer.

Comment: Thanks, once more, Gonzalo Medina. I have tried out your code. It works as given but fails when **\cdots** is replaced with **\sqrt**. Cheers for your response.