# Figcaps and special characters

Tags: packages, unicode, accents, input-encodings

I'm trying to use the `figcaps` package in an article to keep all figures at the end of the document. When I compile the following TeX code using `pdflatex` I get the following error message:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�oS not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Although it says to an `inputenc` error, when I try without using the `figcaps`, everything works smoothly.

Below is an example to illustrate my issue. Please make sure you have an image file named `image_file`. I have tried this sample a couple of times, and the error does not always raise, but in the PDF the captions look awful.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printfigures]{figcaps}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{image_file}
    \caption{Location of the Southeast Brazilian Bight~(SBB) and detail of the São Sebastião Channel.}
    \label{fig:Map}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error raises because I use a special character in the figure caption, in this case `ã` and I suppose a similar error would rise using any of the following characters: `ñ`, `â`, `Ü`, ...

I am aware that a workaround would be to use [escaped codes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) such as `\~a`, for example.

However, I usually find it annoying to use these escaped codes and try to avoid them. Is there any other option?

Comment: egregs answer in [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203804/89976) shines a bit of light on the progress of this as of April 2016. I have not yet updated to TexLive 2016, so I cannot see if these codes have been updated yet. you could solve this by using `utf8x`, but it should be avoided, according to egreg, or God, as I like to call him.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. The same happens with `utf8x`.

Comment: Works fine here, with `utf8x`.

Comment: Compiles with `utf8x` but characters replaced with "[Pleaseinsertintopreamble]". Using `inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c` and `utf8x.def    2004/10/17`

Comment: Apparently it's `figcaps`'s fault.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is similar to the one in [Is it possible to get the package listofsymbols to recognize the \cdots command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228801/). The `figcaps` package uses `\immediate\write` and multibyte UTF-8 characters don't survive it. Also the solution is similar

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[printfigures]{figcaps}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% get a copy of \protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
% patch \FC@writefile to use \protected@iwrite instead of \immediate\write
\long\def\FC@writefile#1#2{\@ifundefined{tf@#1}{}{%
  \expandafter\protected@iwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname{}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{Location of the Southeast Brazilian Bight~(SBB) and detail of the São Sebastião Channel.}
\label{fig:Map}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]