# error when using symbols as endnote marks

Tags: errors, footnotes, endnotes

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{endnotes}

% These work just fine:
%   \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\alph{endnote}}
%   \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\arabic{endnote}}
%   \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\Roman{endnote}}

% But this does not:
    \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\fnsymbol{endnote}}

\begin{document}

This is some text.\endnote{This is an endnote.}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

I'm using Linux Mint 18 with the packages "texworks" (0.5~svn1363-6build2) and "texlive-full" (2015.20160320-1).  Prior to those releases, I had no problem getting symbols to work as endnote marks.  Now, however, it brings up an error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
    \OMS/cmr/m/n/7
l.15 ...is some text.\endnote{This is an endnote.}
```

I've tried the above MWE, and got the same results, so I assume it's not my code.  I need to use both endnotes and footnotes, but in a non-traditional placement.  The latter doesn't give me any trouble, just the former.

**NEW ISSUE:**

Egreg's solution worked for me.  However, I then decided to try the "enotez" package as he suggested in a subsequent post, and now I'm back to the same issue!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
    \usepackage[counter-format=roman]{enotez} % This works.
%   \usepackage[counter-format=symbols]{enotez} % This does not.

\begin{document}

This is my first sentence.\endnote{A notation placed arbitrarily.}

This is my second sentence.%
\footnote{A reference placed at the bottom of the page.}%
\footnote{Another reference.}%
\footnote{Yet another.}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}{heading=\bigskip}
\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask a new question for your new issue. Please also be more specific what “does not work” means. Is there an error message? Are the symbols not printed?

Comment: That's the thing that confused me when Egreg suggested I start a new topic, also.  Using "enotez" was one of his suggestions to the original issue, and it seems to be giving the same error message.  I can start a new topic, but if it gets flagged as being a repeat of this one, I'm not going to take the blame.

Comment: The only difference in error seems to be "\OT1/cmr/m/n/12" instead of "\OMS/cmr/m/n/7".

Comment: `enotez` needs an update anyway. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `endnotes` uses `\write` for its workings. You can fix the problem by defining a “better protected” version of `\fnsymbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}% or memoir or any other class

\usepackage{endnotes}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@pfnsymbol\expandafter{\the\csname c@#1\endcsname}%
}
\protected\def\@pfnsymbol#1{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\pfnsymbol{endnote}}

\begin{document}

This is some text.\endnote{This is an endnote.}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a “conceptually better” solution, which patches the errors in `endnotes.sty` rather than adding a layer at document level.

```
\documentclass{article}% or memoir or any other class

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192133/
% get a copy of `\protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}

% patch endnotes to use \protected@iwrite instead of \immediate\write
\xpatchcmd{\@endnotetext}{\immediate\write\@enotes}{\protected@iwrite\@enotes{}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@endnotetext}{\immediate\write\@enotes}{\protected@iwrite\@enotes{}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@endnotetext}{\immediate\write\@enotes}{\protected@iwrite\@enotes{}}{}{}
% patch endnotes to use \protected@edef instead of \edef
\xpatchcmd{\theendnotes}{\edef\@currentlabel}{\protected@edef\@currentlabel}{}{\ddt}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\theendnote}{\fnsymbol{endnote}}

\begin{document}

This is some text.\endnote{This is an endnote.}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my search for answers, I'd come across using "\protect\fnsymbol", which I tried.  That prevented the error message, but only seemed to leave a blank area where the symbol should've gone.  (The same happened when I tried protecting footnote.)  I'll give your version a try now.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't yet understand the programming aspect of TeX, but your method did work.  Is the problem something that's like to be fixed without the need for a workaround, in the future?

Comment: @Z9zoRtm2 `endnotes.sty` should use a different way of writing to its auxiliary file. You may try `enotez`, which is actively maintained.

Comment: Tried "enotez" package.  Problem resurfaced.  Updated original post.

Comment: @Z9zoRtm2 You should have asked a new question, instead.

Comment: Even though the "new" issue directly involves your solution from this thread, and provides a near-identical error?  I just want to be sure.

Comment: @Z9zoRtm2 Yes, `endnotes` and `enotez` have different approaches.