# Genealogy System

Tags: indexing, genealogytree, genealogy

I'm writing a family history, and I want to do something like this: for every person I have a chapter, and every person is identified by a unique code.

For example something like this:

```
\personChapter{John Doe}{1}

John Doe is born in 1900, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci
elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

that produce this:

> ### John Doe
>
> John Doe is born in 1900, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna
>   aliqua.

In another page I can write this:

```
\personChapter{Jennifer Doe}{23}

Jennifer Doe, born in 1920, is the daughter of \person{1}.
```

that produce this:

> ### Jennifer Doe
>
> Jennifer Doe, born in 1920, is the daughter of [John
>   Doe](http:///)¹.
>
> ---
>
> ¹ See John Doe on page 46.

in which *John Doe* is a link to the John Doe page (in this example page 46).

If I want I can add only the link or only the footnote:

```
Jennifer Doe, born in 1920, is the daughter of \personLink{1}.

Jennifer Doe, born in 1920, is the daughter of \personFoot{1}.
```

I can also specify another name, for example this:

```
John Doe's \person{23}[daughter] is dead in 1990.
```

produce this:

> John Doe's [daughter](http:///)¹ is dead in 1990.
>
> ---
>
> ¹ See Jennifer Doe on page 125.

in which *daughter* is a link to the Jennifer Doe page.

Furthermore, people can have multiple code, for example:

```
\personChapter{Jennifer Doe}{23}[JenniferDoe1920][JD20]
```

Then I can produce an index with all the people.
For every person in the index, is linked the main page of that person:

```
\printPeopleIndex
```

Or, with another command, are linked all the pages in which they are cited:

```
\printPeopleAllRef
```

Is something like this possible?

---

I wrote these commands which partly do what I wrote above.

```
\newcommand{\personChapter}[2]
{
\chapter{#1}
\label{ch:#2}
}

\newcommand{\person}[1]
{
\nameref{ch:#1}
\footnote{See \nameref{ch:#1} on page \pageref{ch:#1} .}
}
```

Comment: A minimal example would be of more use than fragments. What's the purpose of the codes? Why not use just `\chapter` with `\label`s and something like `nameref`?

Comment: Interesting task. How good are your TeX macro programming skills?

Comment: BTW, in LaTeX convention [] denotes an optional argument. However, the person number looks pretty much obligatory to me, suggesting a syntax like `\personChapter{Jennifer Doe}{23}`

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the advice, I wrote two commands that use this: I added them at the end of my question.

Comment: @jknappen I'm not an expert, but I wrote some simple commands that partly do it, but I'm still working on. I also edited the question with LaTeX conventions, as you said, thanks.

Comment: Do you require forward referencing.  For example, Can the text of John Doe on page 1 reference Jennifer Doe on page 7?  Is that allowed, or only referencing on prior pages?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes References must be both forward and backward.

Comment: Forward and backward referencing will require the use of the aux file and multiple-pass compilation to write/read label information.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [And don't forget cycles](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6163683/2657549).

Answer (score 4):

EDITED to use hot links.  It uses the aux file for saving the labeling information, so it can forward and backward reference, as shown in this MWE.

I have implemented `\person` using a footnote link, and `\personLink` implementing a direct link.  EDITED to implement `\personFoot` which provides a plain footnote without a link to the another page.

The `\textheight` is shrunk in this MWE to better show the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\long\def \protected@iwrite#1#2#3{%
     \begingroup
     \let\thepage\relax
     #2%
     \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
     \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
     \reserved@a
     \endgroup
     \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
    }
\newcommand\personChapter[2]{\bigskip%
  \protected@iwrite\@auxout{\def\nex{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand}}{%
    \nex\expandafter\xdef%
    \nex\csname GenLabel#2%
    \nex\endcsname{#1}%
  }%
  \label{Label#2}%
  \noindent\textbf{#1}\smallskip}
\makeatother
\newcommand\person[1]{\csname GenLabel#1\endcsname\footnote{%
  See \csname GenLabel#1\endcsname{} on page \pageref{Label#1}}}
\newcommand\personLink[1]{\csname GenLabel#1\endcsname{} (page \pageref{Label#1})}
\newcommand\personFoot[1]{\csname GenLabel#1\endcsname\footnote{%
  See \csname GenLabel#1\endcsname{} on page \pageref*{Label#1}}}
\parindent 0pt
\textheight 2in
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\personChapter{John Doe}{1}

John Doe is born in 1900, father of \person{23} or, using unlinked footnote,
father of \personFoot{23}, \lipsum[3]

\personChapter{Jennifer Doe}{23}

Jennifer Doe, born in 1920, is the daughter of \person{1} or,
  using no footnote, the daughter of \personLink{1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Note: the `\protected@iwrite` macro came from egreg's answer at [Writing \\ to a File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/writing-to-a-file).

Comment: What is the advantage over the code at the end of my question?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ I don't use up `\chapter`s in the process.

Comment: And what is the advantage to not use `\chapter`?

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ That is for you to decide, if there is any advantage.  Me?  If I used a chapter for each person in the family genealogy, I would have to chop down more trees.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ I have edited the result to use hot links

Comment: *If I used a chapter for each person in the family genealogy, I would have to chop down more trees.* - And if, for example, I use sections? I like your code, but I can not understand the real benefits of it.

Comment: @ᴜsᴇʀ Fair enough.  Each user has his/her own needs.  Best wishes!