# Decouple footnotes from main text

Tags: footnotes

I have a few sentences with a lot of footnotes. Currently my tex code looks like this:

```
This is One%
%
\footnote{
Footnote text 1
}%
%
, Two%
%
\footnote{
Footnote text 2
}%
%
~and Three%
%
\footnote{
Footnote text 2
}%
%
.
```

The code is obviously very hard to read and also error prone with regard to the commas, points and whitespaces following the footnote. I have added the comment lines for better readabilty, but it only helps a little bit. Is there a way to decouple the footnotes from the main text? I know that there are the commands `\footnotemark` and `\footenotetext`, but when I write

```
This is One\footnotemark, Two\footnotemark and Three\footnotemark.

\footnotetext{
Footnote text 1
}
\footnotetext{
Footnote text 2
}
\footnotetext{
Footnote text 3
}
```

all the footnote texts refer to the last footnotemark. I also know that I could use the number parameter (and thereby making the footnote indexes static), but then I would get a problem if I have to add footnoes before or between the existing footnotes. How can I achieve a code like in the second example, but at the same time keep the footnote indexes dynamic?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In the main text, the footnotemarks show the correct indexs (1, 2, 3). But the footnotetexts show only the number 3. Where would I have to increase the footnote counter?

Comment: Sorry, forget my comment, I was wrong.

Comment: Ah, I got the error: `\footnotetext` needs the last `footnote` counter value, i.e. `\footnotemark...\footnotetext{...} but this is the same hurlyburyly as `\footnote{...}` then

Comment: Have a look at the `sepfootnotes` package.

Comment: @clemens Thank you, I will have a look at it and try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\footnotetext` macro is basically meant for referring to a `\footnotemark`, rather near to it, using the current value of the `footnote` counter, however, multiple `\footnotemark` will increase the `footnote` counter accordingly, i.e. in the example it has the value of `3`.

Now, `\footnotetext` will use only `3` as counter value, not the previous one.

A workaround is to reset the footnote counter and automatically step the `footnote` counter each time `\footnotetext` is used, by using `\xpretocmd` (prepending the command with a `\stepcounter`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\footnotetext}{\stepcounter{footnote}}{}{}

\begin{document}



This is One\footnotemark, Two\footnotemark and Three\footnotemark.


\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\footnotetext{%
Footnote text 1
}
\footnotetext{
Footnote text 2
}
\footnotetext{
Footnote text 3
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Another approach, somewhat reinventing `endnotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_rolch_seq 

\NewDocumentCommand{\StoreNote}{+m}{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_rolch_seq {{#1}} % Storing all notes in a list
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowNotes}{}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_rolch_seq {\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{##1}}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\AtEndDocument{%
  \ShowNotes%
}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


This is One\footnotemark, Two\footnotemark and Three\footnotemark.

\StoreNote{A long note}
\StoreNote{Another Long note}
\StoreNote{The note for the footnote with number \number\value{footnote}}

\blindtext[5]

Another\footnotemark

\blindtext[6]

Another footnote anchor is here\footnotemark


\StoreNote{More long notes}
\StoreNote{More other long notes}
\StoreNote{And now for something completely different}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps lot. However, there is an other problem. If have a large document, say 500 pages and 600+ footnotes, then this solution would also get messy, because I have to write all footnote texts at the end of the document. Therefore, I would like to write the footnote texts after each paragraph. E.g. I have a paragraph with 5 footnote and after the paragraph I write the 5 footnote texts. Then I have an other paragraph with 2 footnotes and write after this pargaraph the two footnote texts etc. Because of this I can not set the counter to 0 for each paragaph(current index is unknown)

Comment: @Rolch2015: Well, then use Steven's approach with the `\Lfn` macros. The resetting is only an issue if you have to reset the footnote number after each paragraph. But since all footnotes are at the end, I assume, they have one running number, from 1 to 600+?

Comment: If I could use arithmetic operations (e.g. \setcounter{footnote}{footnote-4})  then I actually would prefer your solution. This would be possible, because I know how many footnotes I have in the pargraph. The tradeoff would be of course that I had to update the subtrahend each time I add a footnote in the pargraph. But I think it would be worth it, because I can decouple the footnotes from the text. Are such operations possible?

Comment: `\setcounter{footnote}{\numexpr\value{footnote}-4}` works ;-). I've got another idea

Comment: @Rolch2015: Is my update more what you need?

Comment: If I use your second solution in my real text I get the errror "! use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition. Furthermore, I would like to have to footnotes at the respective page, but in your example the footnotes are all at the end of the document. However, your first solution together with the subtraction works fine!

Comment: @Rolch2015: Well you wrote that you have to write all footnotes at the end. Perhaps, this was an misunderstanding then

Answer (score 5):

Here I develop what amounts to a labeling system for footnotes.  Define them in the preamble with `\labelfn{label}{footnote}` and recall them in the text with `\Lfn{label}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\labelfn[2]{\expandafter\def\csname Footnote#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\Lfn[1]{\footnote{\csname Footnote#1\endcsname}}
\labelfn{intro}{This is my introductory footnote.}
\labelfn{trivia}{Here is a bit of trivia.}
\labelfn{reminder}{Now for a reminder.}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{6in}
Here is some blah-blah text.\Lfn{intro}  Now as I continue my
text, there is more\Lfn{trivia} to say on the subject.

I am now done.\Lfn{reminder}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Allocating `registers` for this ? ;-) What about `\Lfn{My nice footnote}` ?;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The OP wanted to avoid lengthy footnote text within the body of his/her text, as I understood it.  Coming up with a solution like `\Lfn{My nice footnote}` would put the footnote text right back in amongst the body text, the whole pupose being to avoid this.

Comment: `\Lfn{My nice footnote}` isn't lengthy .... `\Lfn{A ring to rule them all}` is lengthy ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe I should have used `\labelfn{lpsm}{\lipsum[1-5]}` to amplify the point.

Comment: Thank you too! Would it be possible to write the footnote texts at any point in the document, e.g. after each paragraph? There is still one  reservation:  I would have to think of unique identifiers for each footnote, which would be quite cumbersome for 600+ footnotes. I could use numbers, but then when I insert footnotes in between or at the beginning, the order of the numbers would be muddled. Also I would have to look first, which number is the current one, before adding a new footnote. The advantage would be, that I do not have to update the subtrahend (s. comments in Stevens answer).

Comment: @Rolch2015 The problem with numbers is if you need to rearrange footnotes or add extras, it screws up the numbering scheme.  Labels make more sense, as I see it.  There is nothing stopping you from making the label a simple number.  As my solution is structured, the `\labelfn` can occur in the text, but must be defined **before** the footnote can be used.  In order to, for example, define footnotes at the end, one would need a system of writing them all out to the `aux` file, so that the 2nd compilation pass could read them in and use them.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now I understand. Writing such a system would be quite complicated, i guess. Actually I would like to accept both answers in combination, as both lead to my goal, but that is unfortunately not possible. For now I will stick with Steven's answer, as it is the most viable for me, as it does not require many changes. Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: @Rolch2015  For an example of how to write out macros to the aux file, which would allow you to define footnotes at the end, see the addendum to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295482/referencing-a-quote-environment/295485#295485.  Alternatively, consider placing the footnote material in a separate file, and importing it in the preamble with in `\include` or `\input` macro.