# Reference towards a displayquote - Csquotes

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, csquotes, quotation

I have multiple `displayquote`s in a page, and I want to reference a specific one later in the text : e.g. *Given the previous phrase (**specific ref here**)* ...

I have already tried : `\label{itm:phrase_book}` but it's not a numbered item and simply
`\label{phrase_book}` redirects to the section including all the `displayquotes`.

P.s. I don't want to reference to the whole page -as suggested in other posts-.

Any suggestions ? Thank you in advance.

*For instance in page 10 :*

```
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute 
irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\begin{displayquote} 
Tristique [nulla aliquet]$_i$ enim tortor at
auctor. Tortor [dignissim]$_j$ convallis aenean et tortor. 
\end{displayquote}

Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante. 
Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Morbi non arcu risus 
quis varius. 

\begin{displayquote} 
Leo vel orci porta non. [Eget nullam]$_j$ non
nisi est sit amet facilisis. 
\end{displayquote}

Dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Sed lectus vestibulum 
mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. 
Sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc 
pulvinar.

\begin{displayquote} 
Leo vel orci [porta]$_i$ non. Eget nullam non
[nisi]$_j$ est sit amet facilisis. 
\end{displayquote}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

*And now page 15 :*

```
Given the previous phrase (**ref here** : Leo vel orci 
[porta]$_i$ non. Eget nullam non [nisi]$_j$ est sit amet 
facilisis.) 
...
```

Comment: Is there a chance you could number all or at least some of these `displayquote` entities?

Comment: As long as you don't provide code that others can copy and test on their own, how are we suppose to provide any help. Where did you get `displayquote` from?

Comment: @Mico Sure, There are 3 in the same page. Updated my question with an example.

Comment: @daleif Csquotes. Updated my question.

Comment: This is not a minimal example. There is no document class or preamble.

Comment: Maybe that answer helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563198/how-to-reference-a-quote-environment/563217#563217

Comment: What exactly would like like to have as input and output for the "page 15" part? What do you want the document to show for the string `**ref here**`? Do you (always) want the whole text of the quote to be repeated, as in this example? Do you want a hyperlink to the original quote block, or some textual reference?