# Writing Content in the aux files without expansion

Tags: auxiliary-files

I'm creating the XML from the TOC files, in this process I'm finding issue. on looking into the files there are many commands are getting expanded while writing. for example `\hat` has wrote in  `\mathaccentV {tilde}251{A}`. when i have used `\protect` before the `\hat` its writing \hat in the toc. is there any method to produce the same content in the TOC without expansion

```
\documentclass{book} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{This is a sample chapter $\hat{z}acffr$} 
\section{This is a sample section $\tilde{d}$} 
\end{document}
```

Aux file content:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}This is a sample chapter $\mathaccent "705E\relax {z}acffr$}{1}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}This is a sample section $\mathaccent "707E\relax {d}$}{1}}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your response. if possible can you code same example here.

Comment: Is there any way to control this through macros as a global not in the case by case occurrences.

Comment: *You* are supposed to provide the example that you are having difficulty with and then *we* try to adjust it to work.  Please provide a short (but complete) non-working example.

Comment: Does this question help?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/writing-to-a-file

Comment: \documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a sample chapter $\hat{z}acffr$}

\section{This is a sample section $\tilde{d}$}

\end{document}

Comment: it was writing the aux files "\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}This is a sample chapter $\mathaccent "705E\relax {z}acffr$}{1}}" and I need \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}This is a sample chapter $\hat{z}acffr$}{1}} as like in the chapter

Comment: `\MakeRobust{\tilde}` in the preamble.

Comment: i'm getting Undefined control sequence error for \MakeRobust is there any package need to be use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to change the actual `aux` and `toc` files, I just write an additional file, `fauxtoc.toc`, that mimics the toc file, but is unexpanded.

This version is implemented for `\chapter` and `\section`, since that was what was mentioned by OP.  Additional sectioning can be added.

The method draws on egreg's answer to this question: [Writing \\ to a File](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/writing-to-a-file)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
\let\svchapter\chapter
\let\svsection\section
\renewcommand\chapter{\@ifstar{\svchapter*}{\mychapnostar}}
\newcommand\mychapnostar[2][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\svchapter{#2}\fauxtocwrite{chapter}{\thechapter}{#2}%
  \else\svchapter[#1]{#2}\fauxtocwrite{chapter}{\thechapter}{#1}\fi%
}
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\svsection*}{\mysectnostar}}
\newcommand\mysectnostar[2][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\svsection{#2}\fauxtocwrite{section}{\thesection}{#2}%
  \else\svsection[#1]{#2}\fauxtocwrite{section}{\thesection}{#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand\fauxtocwrite[3]{%
    \edef\tmpA{\thepage}%
    \protected@iwrite\tempfile{}{\detokenize{\contentsline{#1}}%
      {\detokenize{\numberline}{#2}\detokenize{#3}}{\tmpA}}%
}
\makeatother
\newwrite\tempfile
\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\tempfile=fauxtoc.toc}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\tempfile}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Sample chapter $\hat{z}acffr$} 
\chapter[$\hat{z}acffr$]{Next}
\section{This is a sample section $\tilde{d}$} 
\end{document}
```

This produces a file `fauxtoc.toc`, which matches the proper toc file, except that the sectioning names are unexpanded

`normal.toc`:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Sample chapter $\mathaccent "705E\relax {z}acffr$}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}$\mathaccent "705E\relax {z}acffr$}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}This is a sample section $\mathaccent "707E\relax {d}$}{5}
```

`fauxtoc.toc`:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Sample chapter $\hat {z}acffr$}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}$\hat {z}acffr$}{5}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}This is a sample section $\tilde {d}$}{5}
```